# Volume of excavated pond

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-3, qgis-processing, volume

I am trying to obtain Cut/Fill Volumes of a large on-site pond using the new Volume Calculation Tool in QGIS.

My files are:

1. DTM (DSM) in TIFF format
2. Contours in DXF and SHP format

I have no problem creating the Polygon but cannot place any of the factors
together to obtain accurate volume with QGIS. Which is 6.7 million gallons.

Comment: Like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sOj_IT8A4Bw ?

Comment: Would you be able to share the .tif file? QGIS works fine for me in terms of volume calculation. The video Mapperz shared is a good resource too (a bit extensive). Worth noting is your projection. If it is in meters, then your volume calc will be in m3 which youll have to convert to gallons manually.

Comment: Which CRS is your data in? How does your output from the tool look like? How have you "placed the factors together"?